# Hard drive partition size wrong. How do I resize without loss of data?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, ext4, fsck

$ fsck

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 610471680 blocks
The physical size of the device is 536870911 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
```

It should be 1 partition but it now shows 2.2tb partitioned and .3tb unpartitioned

[image]

How do I make the first partition correctly be 2.5tb without destroying whatever is in either partition? I did not raid or anything. My devices have been getting repeatedly corrupt by thunderstorms.

Looks like people recommend doing something like  in other places.

> sudo resize2fs /dev/sdc1 610471680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) which can do this job very easily and you will not lost your data any way.

> The best way to access all of the features of the GParted application is by using the GParted Live bootable image. GParted Live enables you to use GParted on GNU/Linux as well as other operating systems, such as Windows or Mac OS X.